# How do you find the view name currently assigned to the web part

Tags: view

How do you find the view name currently assigned to the web part, when you edit the web part it always tells you that the view is 'Current View' if you go to the 'edit the current view' link it brings up a view but does not tell you the name of the view. is there anywhere SharePoint tell you what the name of the currently assigned view is on a web part?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, "Current View" is actually the view for the webpart and does not really have a name as it is not a view in the library as well, but only for the web part.

For example say you change the view to be "My New View" and save the webpart. The next time you go in and edit the webpart it is now current view. You can edit this view and it will not actually make any changes to the view "My New View" in the document library.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Further, if you make changes to My New View in the library it will have no effect on the web part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to find out the view name but there are some things that you can do.  1) In the future, rename the web part title to match the view name. 2) To get the current view criteria: Open the page in Designer, click on the web part, in the code scroll down to "View Name..." and if there is a sort and/or filter on your view you will see these in the "Query" under the View Name.